# how to introduce fault tolerance into beautiful soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm interested in scraping a lot of different websites as quickly as possible. The URLs could have any number of issues for web scraping; e.g., they may refer to files instead of sites, or they may not point to anything real at all. The issue I haven't been able to resolve is what to do when BeautifulSoup hangs, or fails for some reason and doesn't exit. There needs to be a way to stop the html parsing if it can't seem to do it after X seconds. This seems to be remarkably non-trivial, but it seems I'm not the only one, with this website seeming to provide the most relevant information: http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/08/22/how-not-to-set-a-timeout-on-a-computation-in-python

So, given that its quite hard to kill a hanging process such as BeautifulSoup(text) after a certain time has expired, what should I do?

Comment: `bs4` doesn't do the *parsing* itself, they recommend using e.g. `lxml`, so it might be possible to supply your own parser with a timeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Absent some kind of inbuilt functionality in bs4 you can always use multiprocessing.

```
In [1]: from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

In [2]: from multiprocessing import Pool

In [3]: p = Pool(1)

In [4]: j = p.apply_async(BeautifulSoup, ["<html></html>"])

In [5]: j.get(timeout=5)
Out[5]: <html></html>
```

**EDIT: for explanation**

If there is no builtin functionality that supports timeouts for bs4 parsing then multiprocessing is your only option because if you were to run it naively just saying

```
BeautifulSoup(html)
```

then you would be running this instruction in one python process. If in this process, any one of your instructions fails in a way that it just chews up CPU and doesn't exit then you the user will see it occur because it is inside of your shell, and inevitably frustration occurs. In your case `bs4` probably got stuck in some kind of loop trying to parse your html, so if you are running that without multiprocessing then you have no recourse than to either a. kill the process, b. wait for the process to finish.

Multiprocessing allows you to get out of the single process paradigm. Multiprocessing will spawn new python instances that run in the background when you create a pool. The number of instances spawned correspond with the number of workers you allocate to the pool. In our case we just gave the pool one worker. Multiprocessing basically says that if one of its background processes takes too long to return back some results from the command it is given we have the option to kill it. That is essentially what you are doing here.

The difference between Pool.map, Pool.apply, and Pool.apply_async are best left to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool). The map function doesn't have a real purpose for what you're doing because you only need one thread to perform your work. `apply` would work fine but its essentially a synchronous action, it waits for the result to return before continuing. `apply_async` is asynchronous meaning it is good for performing work in parallel. I'm not sure what your specific requirements for your work are so I'll leave the decision of which function to use up to you.

Comment: Hooray. I'm pretty this is it based on my testing. Can you briefly say why you would use apply_async here? I'm having difficulty grasping when I would want: p.apply, p.map, p.apply_async, etc. I found this, which is helpful, but still don't feel like I totally get it. http://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_multiprocessing_intro.html